# BTC number of transactions

Tags: transactions, api, database

I'd like to get number of transaction's data with API.
I already use API of blockchain.info.

Dose someone know other API?
I want to get number of transaction every a minutes(or less than ten minutes).
It's not one day total average.
I mean BTC.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you could use [Bitcoin.com](https://Bitcoin.com) They don't provide API for total transactions but i've got the link they use to get bitcoin total transactions
Here is it:

https://charts.btctest.net/api/chart/daily-transactions
Response Format is JSON.

I guess you could use it.

Comment: Thank you very much.
This is number that is transaction-rate(transaction/second) in a day.

I want to know transaction-rate in a minutes or ten minutes, 
like a 3.5 transaction / second in a minutes.

thanks

Comment: I guess its another question. BTW You have to use some programming language to do this math.